# Adding a tag inside <dependency> tag without repetition in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have a POM file with nearly 100 dependencies defined as follows;

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample.artifact</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${sample.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

However I need to add an  tag inside these dependencies to prevent Maven from downloading transitive dependencies. I'm able to do it as follows;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample.artifact</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${sample.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

However I think adding this  block inside every  reduces the readability since it more than doubles the number of lines in the POM.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The whole approach is "unclean".

First of all, if you use 100 dependencies directly in your source code, there is probably something wrong.

I seems more likely that you do the transitive dependency resolution yourself. This is in most cases not advisable. Every dependency should have its own dependencies. In this way you usually need very few direct dependencies and get the rest as transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
To rephrase the question, is there a way to add a common block inside <dependency> tag?
The scenario you mentioned is to cater a requirement to use a private repository with self-defined groupIds for artifacts. The <exclusions> are to prevent Maven from downloading transitive dependencies (which will fail).

Comment: No. In the long run, you are probably better of if you tidy up the POMs of those dependencies in the private repository. This means, remove transitive dependencies that are not needed (why are they in the POM in the first place?) and add dependencies on other dependencies that are actually needed.